# how to publish a vb project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ms-access-2003

I've finished a system using vb 2008 with an access database. now my problem is I have no idea how to publish it for a user testing. Could anyone help me/ teach me how to publish it.

Answer (score 0):

To publish a website there is a built in tool which allows you to create published website files to a given location.

Follow the steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do this

Hope this helps!